# VB Socket Exception Issue - Ports

Tags: vb.net, sockets

Creating a program that can pass built strings between two computers.

After digging and changing the syntax, I was finally able to see this socket exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
   at ChatProgFinal.chatForm.serverMode()
```

The port that I'm using is 11337.  According to netstat, I'm not using that port, so I'm not certain how else I could be throwing this exception.

Here is my serverMode block:

```
Public Sub serverMode()
    Try
        Dim server As TcpListener = Nothing
        server = New TcpListener(LocalIPEndPointAnyIP)
        server.Start()
        Dim incomingClient As TcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient()

        Do While isAlive = True And incomingClient.Connected = True
            stream = incomingClient.GetStream()
            If stream.CanRead Then
                RaiseEvent DataReceived(stream)
            End If
            If incomingClient.Connected = False Then
                RaiseEvent statusCheck("Disconnected")
                isAlive = False
                server.Stop()
            End If
        Loop
    Catch e As Exception
        RaiseEvent statusCheck(e.ToString)
        Using outfile As New StreamWriter(docPath + "\log.txt")
            outfile.Write(e.ToString)
        End Using
    Finally
        stream.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thank you for any advice you can provide on this.
Side question:  I am not sure how to test/debug software that communicates between two computers through Visual Studio 2010.  What I'm doing right now is publish it and deploy to a test VM.  Anyone have any other methods I could use?

Comment: Only *one* socket can listen on a specific port number, in any process on the machine.  So simple explanations are that, for whatever reason, you might be calling your serverMode() method more than once.  Or you are running your program more than once.  Start by setting a breakpoint on the Start() method call and ensure it only breaks once.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I've run a few tests since you last helped with this question. Hopefully you can still help out. Per my break points, the code block for the server only comes up once. Also, I considered the possibility of the port being closed on my main machine, so I deployed it to a separate laptop instead. Same results with no firewall. Per my logs, it's the "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" message that I had been getting. Tried a few solutions there (Changed ports etc.) Thanks again if you can help. I will post a full question if I need to

Comment: That's an entirely different exception from the one you asked your question about.  Hard to imagine how you consider this "same results".  An "actively refused" is typically a firewall issue.  Ask your LAN administrator to help you out.

Comment: @Hans Passant I apologize about that.  To explain, I went back over things from my earlier attempts.  It seemed the null exception was thrown because the stream was never generated on either side.  (The exception was throwing because server was null in the Finally block)  Digging deeper, I found the "actively refused" issue was the case.  ...it occurs to me as I type this that while my firewalls disabled on my VM and laptop, they were not disabled on the development machine itself.  Thanks, I'll check into this.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Hans's comment, you are probably calling `serverMode` more than once through the life of your program. The one thing I noticed is that in your `finally` block you are not calling `.Stop` on your server, which means its possible to exit `serverMode` without shutting it down. Once that happens, repeated calls to start the server will likely fail.

Comment: Thank you everyone who responded to my question. :)  I will double check the program flow and report back shortly.